# How to implement SciBERT with pytorch; error while loading

Tags: error-handling, neural-network, nlp, tar, word-embedding

I am trying to use SciBERT pre-trained model, namely: scibert-scivocab-uncased the following way:

```
    !pip install pytorch-pretrained-bert 
    import torch
    from pytorch_pretrained_bert import BertTokenizer, BertModel,      BertForMaskedLM 
    import logging
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
    indexed_tokens = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenized_text) 
    segments_ids = [1] * len(tokenized_text)
    tokens_tensor = torch.tensor([indexed_tokens])
    segments_tensors = torch.tensor([segments_ids])
    model =      BertModel.from_pretrained('/Users/.../Downloads/scibert_scivocab_uncased-3.tar.gz')
```

And I get the following error:

```
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

1. I downloaded the file from the website (https://github.com/allenai/scibert)
2. I converted it from "tar" to gzip

Nothing worked.

Any hint on how to approach this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of pytorch-pretrained-BERT i.e. in transformers, you can do the following to load a pretrained model after you un-tar:

import AutoModelForTokenClassification, AutoTokenizer

model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("/your/local/path/to/scibert_scivocab_uncased")

Answer (score 0):

Need to unzip the package and rename the json file to config.json
Then just address the folder pathname where you have unzipped the package. It should work